# Mailkit get message count not working c#

Tags: c#

Hey guys working with emails and c#. I'm working with gmail and MailKit. And let me show you my code.

```
        int firstcount;
        string lastmessage;
        using (var client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
            client.Authenticate("xxxxxblah@gmail.com", "blahblahpassword");

            firstcount = client.GetMessageCount();
            MessageBox.Show(firstcount.ToString());
            var messager = client.GetMessage(firstcount - 1);
            lastmessage = messager.TextBody.ToString();
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
```

Anyways i put in the MessageBox.Show to show me what number it is getting and it comes back with 0. Even tho I have 3 messages all unread in my gmail mail box. Any suggestions or ideas or what i'm doing wrong. I did however open all these messages via mail.google.com but since then i have set them to unread.

Thanks for the help as always.

Comment: What is available to the POP3 server and what is available via the web front end are not always the same.

Comment: But just a few seconds ago it was working and showing all 3 emails. So say it gets read via pop before can it not get read again @SamAxe Also, anyway to make it reappear in pop?

Comment: I have the same issue. The email is marked as unread in gmail, but when its been 'read' using Pop3 in your application it doesnt appear again when you try to get the messages on a subsequent connection. Is this the normal behaviour?